# Angular - Get data into ng-Model from object in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I am not able to put the data into ng-model in view from an object in controller.

VIEW1 :

```
<input type="text" class="user-input" name="profile.firstname" ng-model="profile.firstname" ng-minlength="2" required pattern=".{2,}" placeholder="E.g. Anvika" title="Please enter atleast 2 characters">
```

When I click a button in VIEW2, it fires a function (say function 'test').

VIEW2

```
<input type="submit" ng-click="register.test()" ui-sref="doctorRegister" value="Profile">
```

CONTROLLER:

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller('registerController', ['$scope', 'tempDataStorageService', function ($scope, tempDataStorageService) {


var register = this;
register.doctor = {};
register.test = function () {
    register.refreshProfile = tempDataStorageService.get(register.doctor.profile);
    //console.log(register.refreshProfile);
    var a = register.refreshProfile.firstname;
    console.log(a);     
}
}
```

TempDataStorageService:

```
var app = angular.module('app'); 
app.factory('tempDataStorageService', function() {
    var savedData = {};
    function set(data) {
        savedData = data;
    }
    function get() {
        return savedData;
    }

    return {
        set: set,
        get: get
    }
});
```

EDIT: I have tried to show the declaration of the controller as well, if that helps. 
How can I make it so that when I click on the Profile button on VIEW2, it populates VIEW1 with the data?

Comment: That's your entire controller? Could you provide `ng-controller` declaration and the rest of your controller ?

Comment: Hey @LenilsondeCastro the entire controller is huge, I just gave you the parts I thought necessary. Though, let me abstract the code and give you the declaration too..

Comment: Hey @LenilsondeCastro ... Edited and declared the controller.

Comment: You are passing a parameter in `tempDataStorageService.get()` and yet your get function doesn't accept a parameter.

Comment: do you declare your controller using `controllerAs`? because if you aren't then you can't use `var register = this;` in the controller, you must bind functions to the `$scope` instead

Comment: Hey @Will.Harris .. Yes, I've declared the controller using controllerAs.

Comment: You should use `controllerAs register` and then on your template `ng-model="register.profile.firstName"` and make sure that `profile` is declared on your controller as `this.profile` or `register.profile` if you are using `var register = this;`

Comment: Yes sir. Done that already. doesn't work. That's why I'm here on stack

Comment: We don't know how you are populating `register.profile` yet. If you are using `controllerAs register` you have to use `ng-model="register.profile.firstName"` by the way (your sample code doesn't show this).

Comment: how about giving a plnkr link with the above code.??

Comment: Hey people. Thanks for the assist. I decided to get rid of the "controllerAs" syntax and only do the "controller" in the ui router so that I am able to bind the models with the root scope and finally got it to work. Thank you anyway, people. This is something that I will research as and when I get time to spare!

Comment: Pretty sure, that Lenilson's last answer would have led to the same result. If you use controllerAs, you have to use register.profile.firstname.

Comment: Yeah. That's what the official documentation says as well. I just had to finish that project in time so I did what I could do fast. Thanks anyway @Daniel ...

Answer (score 0):

**The plunker:**

[Working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/RrbCMp6ApOWB9BG5xIZ0?p=preview)

**The html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">

    <form>
      <h2 class="text-primary">Get data into ng-Model from object in controller</h2>
      <hr>
      <div class="form-group">
        <h3 ng-class="!mainCtrl.firstName? 'text-danger' : 'text-success'">Enter Name</h3>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="mainCtrl.firstName" placeholder="E.g. Anvika">
      </div>


      <hr>
      <h3 class="text-info">This is what you are typing: {{mainCtrl.firstName}}</h3>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="mainCtrl.test()">Save Name</button>
    </form>

    <hr>
    <h3 class="text-info">This is what is stored</h3>
    <h4>Doctor first name: {{mainCtrl.storedData.doctorFirstName}}</h4>
  </body>

</html>
```

**The JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['tempDataStorageService', function(tempDataStorageService) {

  var register = this;

  register.firstName = "";

    register.storedData = tempDataStorageService;

    register.test = function () {
      tempDataStorageService.setName(register.firstName);
    }

}]);


app.factory('tempDataStorageService', function() {
    // The service object
    var profile = {};

    profile.doctorFirstName = "No doctor data stored";

    //The functions

    profile.setName = function(data) {
        profile.doctorFirstName = data;
    }

    profile.getName = function() {
        return profile.doctorFirstName;
    }

    // return the service object
    return profile;
});
```

**Recommendations:**

1. Please properly format code when asking questions.
2. As good practice use a style guide. A good starting point is [John
   Papa's Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)